# Prove by mathematical induction for any prime number$ p > 3, p^2 - 1$ is divisible by $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove by mathematical induction for any prime number $p > 3,  p^2 - 1$ is divisible by $3$?

Actually the above expression is divisible by $3,4,6,8,12$ and $24$.

I have proved the divisibility by $4$ like:
$$
\begin{align}
p^2 -1 &= (p+1)(p-1)\\
       &=(2n +1 +1)(2n + 1 - 1)\;\;\;\text{as $p$ is prime, it can be written as $(2n + 1)$}\\
       &= (2n + 2)(2n)\\
       &= 4(n)(n + 1)
\end{align}
$$
    Hence $p^2 - 1$ is divisible by 4.

But I cannot prove the divisibility by $3$.

Comment: This is easy to prove by modular arithmetic but I don't see how to prove it using induction.

Comment: @fretty: We just need to take two cases $3n+1$ and $3n-1$ for proving this by mathematical induction.

Comment: But that isn't inductive, that is a direct proof. The inductive hypothesis would be that if $p_k^2-1$ is divisible by $3$ then $p_{k+1}^2-1$ is. How do you prove this...

Comment: You should say "as $p$ is an *odd* prime". Clearly $2$ cannot be written as $2n+1$... By the way, you actually proved divisibility by $8$, since $n(n+1)$ is even for every integer $n$.

Comment: It is already stated in the question that p > 3 so 2 is not being considered here.

Yes I am just unable to prove it for 3.

Comment: @fretty: You'd rather play safe with natural numbers in induction. You can never trust on *primes*.

Comment: But this is not what we are trying to prove, the statement we are proving by induction is that the $n$th prime satisfies the divisibility criterion...this is certainly not true for all natural numbers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p>3$ is a prime then $3$ does not divide $p$ i.e. $3$ and $p$ are relatively prime , now $p-1$ , $p , p+1$ are three consecutive integers , so one of them must be divisible by $3$ , hence $3$ must divide their product i.e. ,  $p(p-1)(p+1)=p(p^2-1)$ , but $3$ and $p$ are relatively prime , so $3$ must divide $p^2-1$

Comment: Thanks Souvik for the answer.

Comment: @Arghya : You are welcome any time.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$p \equiv 1$ or $-1 (\mod3) \implies p^2 \equiv 1 (\mod 3)$ for every $p>3$

Comment: I didn't understand please elaborate?

Comment: @Arghya every integer is either of the form $3n-1$, $3n+1$, or $3n$, if its divisible by $3$ then were done, so we might as well assume its either congruent to $-1$ or $1$ modulo $3$